# Pass 2 or more variables to django template

Tags: python, django-templates

i want to pass 2 lists to django template but only first is rendered
this is index.html:

```
enter code here
{% if latest_poll_list %}
<ul>
{% for poll in latest_poll_list %}
    <li>{{ poll.question }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
{% else %}
<p>No polls are available.</p>
{% endif %}

{% if menu_items_list %}
    <table id="menu_items_list">
<tr>
    {% for item_url, item_name in menu_items_list %}
    <td><a href="item_url">item_name</a>
    {% endfor %}
    </tr>
</table>
 {% endif %}
<h3>{{ index_name }}</h3>
```

and this is urlconf:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('zzz.polls.views',
url(r'^$',
    ListView.as_view(
    queryset=Poll.objects.order_by('pub_date')[:5],
    context_object_name='latest_poll_list',
    template_name='index.html')),
```

and views:

```
def index(request):
    latest_poll_list = Poll.objects.all().order_by('pub_date')[:5]
    index_name = 'INDEX PAGE'
    menu_items_list = ['somesite.com', 'Googy') for x in xrange(5)]
    return render_to_response('index.html', {'latest_poll_list': latest_poll_list,
                                             'menu_items_list' : menu_items_list,
                                             'index_name': index_name})
```

where i make mistake??

Answer (score 1):

The syntax of the LC is wrong.

```
>>> ['somesite.com', 'Googy' for x in xrange(5)]
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    ['somesite.com', 'Googy' for x in xrange(5)]
                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> [('somesite.com', 'Googy') for x in xrange(5)]
[('somesite.com', 'Googy'), ('somesite.com', 'Googy'), ('somesite.com', 'Googy'), ('somesite.com', 'Googy'), ('somesite.com', 'Googy')]
```